# SCP not exiting on failure (on latest Ubuntu and Linux Alpine)

Tags: scp

I am using latest Linux Alpine (3.6) as OS in a docker container (also tested on Ubuntu 16.10 outside of Docker with same result).

I have installed openssh (`apk add openssh`).

Here is my command :

```
scp -i $KEY_PATH -P $PORT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST:$FILENAME .
```

When scp successfully copies a file, it exists with 0 (expected).

When the file is not found, scp says : `No such file or directory` but does not exits. What can I do to get a proper exit with a non 0 code ? Could it be a problem on the server or network ?

Comment: As an aside, double-quote your variables, such as `"$KEYPATH"`. Try to avoid using `$USER` - you're either overriding a standard variable or it's an unnecessary part of the command (and just use `"$HOST:$FILENAME"`)

Comment: Where would $USER be defined elsewhere ? inside the key ?

Comment: It's defined by `login` and inherited from the shell (`bash` or whatever). For your own variables it's general better to use lower case names.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you have some friends who have some intels about the question itself, I'd be rly grateful.